# Why is $\int$ $1\over(a^2+b^2)^{3/2}$ $da$ $ = $ $ a\over b^2\sqrt {(a^2+b^2)}$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{da}{(a^{2}+b^{2})^{3/2}}  =\frac{a}{b^{2}\sqrt{(a^{2}+b^{2})}}.$$

Found this in the solution to a problem in my physics textbook, and left clueless.

Comment: The R.H.S. must contains an arbitrary constant, as the integration is indefinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the trig substitution $a = b\tan \theta$, we get $a^2 + b^2 = b^2\sec^2\theta$ (since $\tan^2\theta + 1 = \sec^2\theta$), so $(a^2 + b^2)^{3/2} = b^3\sec^3\theta$. Since $da = b\sec^2\theta\, d\theta$, we obtain

$$\int \frac{1}{(a^2 + b^2)^{3/2}}\, da = \int \frac{1}{b^3\sec^3\theta} b\sec^2\theta\, d\theta = \frac{1}{b^2}\int \frac{d\theta}{\sec \theta} = \frac{1}{b^2}\int \cos \theta\, d\theta = \frac{1}{b^2}\sin\theta + C = \frac{a}{b^2\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} + C.$$

Answer (score 1):

To compute the integration just put, $$a=b\tan \theta.$$

Then try it. I think you can do it. If need more details tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, letting $a=b\sinh t$, we are left with $~\displaystyle\frac1{b^2}\int\frac{dt}{\cosh^2t}$ , which can be evaluated using $u=e^t$ to transform the integrand into a rational function, and then either [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) or employing [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).